# Not getting Image name and its Extension

Tags: html, jsp

JSP code :

```
<% String path="";
File f = new File("D:/.../WebContent/UploadedFiles");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
path=files[i].getPath(); } %>
```

When i put this as image src="<%=path%>" i get the whole path as D:\Java\Abc\image.png

Problem is i dont want the whole path. I just want the image name and its extension. For eg: "image.png" is the only thing i want.
Would appreciate your Answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then don't use the path, [use the name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29):

```
path = files[i].getName();
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It worked. But thing is that when i restart internet explorer. Its not detecting the new image name. It still shows me the first image which i tried to paste. What could be the prob?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `files[i].getName()` instead?

BTW: Please avoid using JSP scriptlets! Your code qualifies for being used as part of a servlet.

Comment: I m implementing jsp code in html page. What i m trying to do is i select an image from computer through input file and then when i click on submit it loads the jsp form which calls the above functionality to display the image selected in d div.

Comment: Anyway it would be much clearer if you had a servlet collecting your file names, putting them in some Java container and storing them in a request attribute. Your JSP could simply iterate over the container's content and display the names. Voilà.

Comment: I want to do it with jsp because i find it simple. See problem i am facing is that when i run the jsp file, i get the image name and its displayed on the div. Then 2nd time when i try to run the page the image doesnt change i.e. It still shows me the previous image.

Comment: It _is_ simple. Yet it is my experience that it always pays to invest in design: Your simple code will grow bigger as you program, and changing its structure will get harder - so in the end you find yourself with a huge lump of code which is close to impossible to maintain, and you will spend weeks refactoring it, ever scared of breaking something. I have seen a lot of that. One more point: Your code posted at SO has a chance be looked at by many people, thinking "Ok, that's the way you write JSP!" Please give them good examples to learn from!

Comment: For your added question about data not being updated, please be so kind as to start a new SO question and be more verbose. I do not quite understand the problem you have.